# Check BGP status

Tags: python-3.x

I recently had an interview and was asked to write a code that logs into 3 routers and reloads each, one at a time - checks that BGP is established and the interfaces are up before moving to reload the next device. We have been provided an imported module that can SSH into the router and reload it. Thoughts anyone? I'm new to Python

Though a module was provided for SSH, I started by coding it out and here is what I tired; just to give an idea of how the router works and what I am checking for:

```
import socket
import paramiko


def run_ssh_command(username, password, host, command):
    """
    Using paramiko to SSH into remote locations and run commands
    """
    port = 22
    s = paramiko.SSHClient()
    s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        s.connect(host, port, username, password, look_for_keys=False, timeout=5.0)
    except paramiko.AuthenticationException as e:
        print("authentication failed: ", e)
        s.close()
        return
    except socket.timeout as e:
        print("socket timeout: ", e)
        s.close()
        return
    except paramiko.SSHException as e:
        print("SSH Exception: ", e)
        s.close()
        return
    except socket.error as e:
        print("socket error: ", e)
        s.close()
        return
    (stdin, stdout, stderr) = s.exec_command(command)
    print ("ran command ", command)
    # for line in stdout.readlines():
    # print(line)
    s.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        run_ssh_command("CompRouter", "backbonedevice", "10.10.10.25", "show ip bgp summary")
```

So my line of thought is to SSH to the device, issue a "show ip bgp summary" command - this is what the table typically looks like:

```
Neighbor       V        AS    MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ Up/Down  Statd
10.10.10.2     4       65536       7       7        1    0    0 00:03:04      0
```

The idea is to check that the InQ/OutQ values are zero or non of the BGP neighbor are "Down", then and only then do I move to reload the next router.

This is particularly where I am stuck. Given a table like this, how to I check the entire InQ/OutQ column (there might be more than one neighbor) and then take the necessary action?

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** since you barely provided any detail about your attempt or how your router works.

Comment: Thanks. You're right that I should have included what I have already tired. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Opted to use `napalm` and `netmiko` - works like a charm:

```
from simplecrypt import encrypt, decrypt
from pprint import pprint
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from napalm import get_network_driver
import json
#from time import time
import time

def read_device_data(devices_filename):

    devices = {} #Create a dictionary for each IP's unique info

    with open(devices_filename) as device_info:
        for lines in device_info:
            this_dev = lines.strip().split(',')
            dev = {'ipaddr': this_dev[0],
                   'type': this_dev[1],
                   'name': this_dev[2]}
            devices[dev['ipaddr']] = dev

    print('Displaying info for all devices below: ')
    pprint(devices)
    return devices

#Create a function to decrypt and read file containing credentials encrypted in the format ip,username,password 

def read_device_creds(device_cred_filename, key):

    print('\n Decoding encrypted device credentials....')

    with open(device_cred_filename, 'rb') as device_creds_file:
        device_creds_decry = decrypt(key, device_creds_file.read())

    device_creds_list = json.loads(device_creds_decry.decode('utf-8'))
    pprint(device_creds_list)
    print('\n Displaying device credentials in dictionary format:')
    """
    Convert device_creds_list to dictionary using list comprehension
    """
    device_creds_dict = {this_dev[0]: this_dev for this_dev in device_creds_list}
    print(device_creds_dict)
    return device_creds_dict

def check_BGP(net_device, cred):


    print(f"Connecting to {net_device['ipaddr']} right now to check BGP status.....")

    while True:

        try:
            driver = get_network_driver('ios')
            iosv = driver(net_device['ipaddr'], cred[1], cred[2])
            iosv.open()

        except:
            print('Waiting to establish a socket...')

        else:
            time.sleep(30)
            ios_output = iosv.get_bgp_neighbors()

            for k,v in ios_output.items():
                for y in v.values():
                    if type(y) == dict:
                        for z in y.values():
                            print(f"BGP peer is up? {z['is_up']}")
                            return z['is_up'] == True

def reload(creds):

    iosv_device = {
        'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
        'ip': creds[0],
        'username': creds[1],
        'password': creds[2]
    }

    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**iosv_device)
    output = net_connect.send_command_timing('wr mem')
    time.sleep(10)
    output += net_connect.send_command_timing('reload')
    output += net_connect.send_command_timing('y')
    print(output)


def is_alive(alive_dev, alive_cred): #check if device is back online after reload

    while True:

        try:
            driver = get_network_driver('ios')
            iosvl2 = driver(alive_dev['ipaddr'], alive_cred[1], alive_cred[2])
            iosvl2.open()
        except:
            print(f"Attempting to reconnect to {alive_cred[0]}")
        else:
            alive_output = iosvl2.is_alive()
            print(alive_output)
            return alive_output['is_alive'] == True
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':

    net_devices = read_device_data('devices_data')
    net_creds = read_device_creds('encrypted_device_creds', 'cisco')

#    starting_time = time()

    for ipadd, device_info in net_devices.items():
        print(net_devices.items())

        while True:

            print (f'Connecting to: {ipadd}')

            if  check_BGP(device_info, net_creds[ipadd]) == True:
                print(f'Reloading {ipadd} now')
                reload(net_creds[ipadd])

            else:
                print(f'Re-checking BGP on {ipadd}')

            if is_alive(device_info, net_creds[ipadd]) == True and check_BGP(device_info, net_creds[ipadd]) == True:
                print(f'{ipadd} back online and BGP OK!')
                break
            else:
                print('Router down or BGP failed to reconverged; exiting script')
                break



#    print ('\n---- End get config sequential, elapsed time=', time() - starting_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, I wrote a code that detects BGP route limits. Its purpose is to calculate the route limit rate by learning the information under the Interfaces. In this regard, I recommend the TTP module, where you can create your own templates.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from getpass import getpass
from pprint import pprint
from ttp import ttp
from genie.testbed import load
from pprint import pprint
import json
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from netmiko import Netmiko

        #**************************************************************************************************************************

with open("user_pass.txt", "r") as f5:
        user_pass = f5.readlines()

for list_user_pass in user_pass:
        if "username" in list_user_pass:
                username = list_user_pass.split(":")[1].strip()
        if "password" in list_user_pass:
                password = list_user_pass.split(":")[1].strip()

def _ssh_(nodeip):
        try:
                huawei = {
                        'device_type': 'huawei', 'ip': nodeip, 'username':
                        username, 'password': password, }
                con = Netmiko(**huawei)
                print(nodeip.strip() + "  " + "basarili giris")
        except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                f_3.write(nodeip.strip() + "\n")
                return

        #**************************************************************************************************************************
        
        data_to_parse_0 = con.send_command_timing('display ip vpn-instance | ignore-case i Customer_A') 

        print(data_to_parse_0)

        ttp_template_0 ="""
  {{Customer_Name}}                             {{nodeip}}     {{IPV4}}
"""
        parser_0 = ttp(data=data_to_parse_0, template=ttp_template_0)
        parser_0.parse()

        #print result in JSON format
        results_0 = parser_0.result(format='json')[0]
        print(results_0)

        #str to list **convert with json.loads
        result_0 = json.loads(results_0)
        print(result_0[0]["Customer_Name"])

        #**************************************************************************************************************************
        data_to_parse = con.send_command_timing("display current-configuration configuration vpn-instance  {}".format(result_0[0]["Customer_Name"]))
        print(data_to_parse)

        ttp_template ="""
  {{routing-table}} limit {{ total_number | DIGIT }} {{total_number2}}
"""
        parser = ttp(data=data_to_parse, template=ttp_template)
        parser.parse()

        #print result in JSON format
        results = parser.result(format='json')[0]
        print(results)

        #str to list **convert with json.loads
        result = json.loads(results)
        print(result)

        #**************************************************************************************************************************

        data_to_parse_2 = con.send_command_timing('dis ip routing-table vpn-instance' + " " + result_0[0]["Customer_Name"] + " " + " statistics | i Summary Prefixes")

        print(data_to_parse_2)

        ttp_template_2 ="""
Summary Prefixes : {{ used_number | DIGIT }}
"""

        parser2 = ttp(data=data_to_parse_2, template=ttp_template_2)
        parser2.parse()

        #print result in JSON format
        results2 = parser2.result(format='json')[0]
        print(results2)

        #str to list **convert with json.loads
        result2 = json.loads(results2)
        print(result2[0]["used_number"])

        #**************************************************************************************************************************

        result3 = (int(result2[0]["used_number"]) / int(result[0]["total_number"])) * 100
        print(int(result3))

        with open("vrf_limit_result.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write("Customer_Result" +"_" + nodeip +"==>" + str(result3)+ "\n")
                f.close()

        #**************************************************************************************************************************

f_2 = open("ip_list.txt", "r")
ip_list = f_2.readlines()
f_2.close()
f_3 = open("Ssh_unconnected_2.txt", "w")

# Therading method
myPool = ThreadPool(100)
result = myPool.map(_ssh_, ip_list)
```